# Is the source code for fl.containers.ScrollPane (and the other fl.* components) available?

Tags: flash

I'm using the CS3 fl.* controls in a flash application, and there appears to be a bug in the ScrollPane implementation. It would be great to have the source code to find a work-around. Is this available anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Flash comes with all of the source code available for its components.

You can find them in your Flash install directory. My default install places the ScrollPane class here:

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS3\en\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface\fl\containers

Just make sure you make a backup before you make any changes.

What is the issue you are experiencing with the scrollpane?

Answer (score 0):

The [Spark Project](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/WikiStart/en) appears to have some code you might be interested in .. for example [here](http://www.libspark.org/browser/mxp/specialbutton/as3/src/fl/containers?rev=1927)